# how to insert to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

My 'fruit' db looks something like:

```
apple red 4
orange orange 3
```

What I don't get is `$query ="insert into fruit"` part, I have it because as I press F5, I want it to print:

```
apple red 4
orange orange 3
apple red 4
apple red 4...
```

like since I have it `$query`, I want it insert it to my db again and again as I press F5?.. if that makes sense..?

Please look at my code and see what is wrong.

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","yoo1014");
    mysql_select_db("eyydb", $connect);

    $query = "insert into fruit ('apple','red',4);
    mysql_query($query, $connect);

    $query = "select * from fruit";

    $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);

    while($fruit=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $fruit["name"] . " " . $fruit["color"] . " " . $fruit["amount"] . "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: 1) don't use `mysql_*`, and; 2) check for errors (I recommend using PDO/mysqli with Exceptions enabled *and* trying queries out in phpMyAdmin or the mysql CLI)

Comment: you forgot values before ( in insert query

Comment: and also you did not close quote after query. First check syntax values before you post code here.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic I did fiix the quote but I don't understand what you mean when you say (...

Comment: insert query goes like "insert into table values ('values here')"

Comment: (easier read as `INSERT INTO table VALUES ('foo', 'bar')`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that:

```
   $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","yoo1014");
   mysql_select_db("eyydb", $connect);

   $query2="insert into fruit (name, color,amount) VALUES('apple','red',4)";
   mysql_query($query2, $connect);

   $query="select * from fruit";

    $result=mysql_query($query, $connect);

   while($fruit=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $fruit["name"]."<br> ";
    echo $fruit["color"]." <br>";
    echo $fruit["amount"]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$query = "insert into fruit
(fruit_name,color,quantity)
VALUES('apple','red',4)";
```